# Was there a barge landing attempt on Launch 16 (EUTELSAT 115 / ABS 3A) March 1st

Tags: spacex, landing, falcon-9

I've been reading here (SX) and SpaceX website and other sites and can see no reference to any attempt to try the barge landing of the first stage booster on the recent Falcon-9 launch on March 1st. Everything is totally Schtum, no confirmation *or* denial.

Anyone know what happened to the first stage of the [1st March Launch](http://www.spacex.com/news/2015/03/01/falcon-9-launches-two-all-electric-communications-satellites)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No.  [The booster did not even have landing legs.](http://www.spaceflight101.com/spacex-falcon-9---eutelsat-115-west-b--abs-3a-launch-updates.html)

> To loft the two payloads with a total mass of 4,159 Kilograms into a Supersynchronous Transfer orbit required almost the entire performance of Falcon 9, not permitting the first stage to attempt a boost-back and propulsive landing because it had to burn its entire propellant load during the primary mission of boosting the second stage on its trajectory. With no option for a landing, the first stage was flown without landing legs and without grid fins.

Comment: Note that this might change pretty soon. According to [Elon Musk via Twitter](https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/572257004938403840): _Upgrades in the works to allow landing for geo missions: thrust +15%, deep cryo oxygen, upper stage tank vol +10%_. More information on the Eutelsat 115 West B & ABS 3A launch [here](http://www.spaceflight101.com/spacex-falcon-9---eutelsat-115-west-b--abs-3a-launch-updates.html).

Comment: OTOH, there's nothing to stop SpaceX from taking contracts for larger payloads that need 100% of the upgraded F9's thrust precluding recovery again.

Answer (score 2):

The delays in Falcon Heavy launching has led to SpaceX having contracts to launch payloads that are too big to land the first stage.

There are several payloads that needed more performance than is available from a reusable Falcon 9. The Falcon Heavy was meant to be used but was not ready.  Thus to fullfill the contracts they launched on Falcon 9 in expendable mode.

This provides the 30% of payload lost for recovering the stage to the payloads mission.

Additionally the absence of legs, grid fins, cold gas thrusters mean the first stage is a bit lighter and thus more performance again.